# How to add JQuery in a DotNet generated Angular project?

Tags: javascript, angular

I've to do some initialization for my theme after the view has been initialized.
I've implemented `AfterViewInit`, I've managed to import jquery:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

But now I need to execute this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(document).trigger('nifty.ready');
}
```

And I've trouble, because it seems that at this point, document is not known. I guess I should have another `import`, but I can't find from where?
My whole `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        $(document).trigger('nifty.ready');
    }
}
```

The error I get:

> Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'document' of undefined at module.exports.module.exports
>   (E:\My\Clients\AppClientApp\dist\vendor.js:12879:12) at
>   AppComponent.ngAfterViewInit

**EDIT**

You can find [here](https://github.com/jgrossrieder/Astro/tree/master/Clients/Astro.Clients.Web) the whole web app part.

**EDIT2**
In fact I've the impression that jquery is not initialized properly at all, once loaded(without error), `window.jquery` return `undefined`... any idea why?

Comment: Post your full code, looks like you are using document in a node module which does not exist

Comment: @Dummy : If I remove the `$(document)...` line, everything is working. I added the whole class

Comment: Try `import $ from 'jquery';` I use `document` just fine inside `ngOnInit` in my app

Comment: "document" reference works fine in a typescript application. Did you try to rename $ -> J

Comment: @Dummy, I tried, but I still get the `Call to Node module failed with error: ReferenceError: document is not defined`

Comment: @Karbos538 I tried the answer from AJey above, no success either :(

Comment: Try this `document.body.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('nifty.ready'));`

Comment: How did you install jQuery ? Are you using angular-cli ?

Comment: @Karbos538 I took the template from .Net `dotnet new angular`.

Comment: I suspect the root of the problem is that the template project created with "dotnet new angular" tries to render the whole page on the server. But there is no window object on the server, and without a window object, the attempt to reference jquery will fail, because the vendor.js file uses a factory that requires a window to return jquery -
without it you get the "jQuery requires a window with a document" error.  If I am right, maybe this comment can help point someone in the right direction to find a solution - I'm stuck myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the document in your component.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DOCUMENT-let.html

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {DOCUMENT} from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) {
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a step forward, now I've another error: `Call to Node module failed with error: Error: jQuery requires a window with a document`

Comment: I have the same error: "jQuery requires a window with a document". Has anyone figured out how to address this error? I got this far using import * as $ from 'jquery' in the app.component.ts file, but do not know how to get past this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing jquery try this -

```
declare var jQuery:any;

jQuery(document);
```

console.log jQuery(document) to be sure

P.S make sure jquery is available on the window scope!

Comment: I get some `Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` now. What do you mean by `available on the window scope`? How do I do that?

Comment: How are you installing jquery and how does your build system look like?

Comment: Most probably I think you are getting the error because jquery is not available on window scope

Comment: jquery is installed through NPM, and included within the webpack vendor list

Comment: You can find the webpack.vendor.js here: https://github.com/jgrossrieder/Astro/blob/master/Clients/Astro.Clients.Web/webpack.config.vendor.js 

This is my actual version, I just commented the call to jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look to your project. Well, I didn't test all the .Net features, but I guess your webpack config misses a plugin provider for jQuery (used to be done by angular-cli).

So you ever done :

```
npm install jquery --save
```

Try this :

```
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
```

And then add the jquery plugin provider to your [webpack.config.js](https://github.com/jgrossrieder/Astro/blob/master/Clients/Astro.Clients.Web/webpack.config.js) :

```
  plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery'
      })
    ]
```

Finally import it as follow :

```
import "jquery";
declare var $: any;
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, the jquery seems to be listed as a npm dependency already, no? and I just saw now there a jquery provide plugin in webpack.config.vendor.js:
`new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)`

Comment: Right. I didn't see it. So you may have jquery as a global variable. Try to remove your `import * as $ from 'jquery';` and eventually check your are not installing 2 jquery packages...

Comment: if I remove it, I've this: `Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: ReferenceError: jquery is not defined`

Comment: Ok just try another suggestion that works for me (I edited my answer)